# How to Write Generic Function in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying to write a general argmin function in Swift.  Here is my code:

```
func argmin<X, Y:Comparable, R:SequenceType, where X== R.Generator.Element>
    (f:(X)->Y, domain:R)->X{
       var gen = domain.generate()
       var best = gen.next()!
       var minval = f(best)
       while let this = gen.next() {
           let value = f(this)
           if value < minval {
               best = this
               minval = value
           }
    }
    return best
}
```

I get the error message "Expected identifier to name generic parameter" when I try to compile this definition.  I have no idea what this means.  It sounds like an error one would get on calling the function, not defining it, but even then, I wouldn't understand it.

I'm just starting to learn Swift.  Can you explain this message? (BTW, I know this function will blow up if called with an empty sequence.  I'm not worrying about that yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove this comma:

```
func argmin<X, Y:Comparable, R:SequenceType, where X== R.Generator.Element>
                                           ^
```

Placed that, it tells the compiler there's another generic parameter. The error message just says that - maybe in a cryptic way, but once you know, it's clearer what it means

Comment: That did it, thanks.  I'll know what the error message means next time.